# Correct parameters for rotation using $BitmapDecoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync

Tags: powershell

I have this PowerShell code:

```
$AsyncTask = $BitmapDecoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync()
```

But discovered that some of the images coming in are rotated, so experimenting I came up with this:

```
$BmTf = [BitmapTransform]::new()
$BmTf.Rotation = [BitmapRotation]::None
# $BmTf.Rotation = [BitmapRotation]::Clockwise90Degrees
# $BmTf.Rotation = [BitmapRotation]::Clockwise180Degrees
# $BmTf.Rotation = [BitmapRotation]::Clockwise270Degrees
$AsyncTask = $BitmapDecoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync(
    [BitmapPixelFormat]::Bgra8,
    [BitmapAlphaMode]::Ignore,
    $BmTf,
    [ExifOrientationMode]::IgnoreExifOrientation,
    [ColorManagementMode]::DoNotColorManage
)
```

While it does work, I'm not familiar BitmapPixelFormat, or the other parameters.  The documentation for [GetSoftwareBitmapAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder.getsoftwarebitmapasync) doesn't appear to give any hints on what the default value it is using for BitmapPixelFormat.

Does anyone know the best values to pass to the version of GetSoftwareBitmapAsync() that takes 5 parameters to mimic the version of GetSoftwareBitmapAsync() that takes 0 parameters?

**EDIT:**

Just found out that trying `[BitmapPixelFormat]::Unknown` causes this error:

> Exception calling "GetSoftwareBitmapAsync" with "5" argument(s): "The
> parameter is incorrect. Windows.Graphics.Imaging: The bitmap pixel
> format is unsupported."

But no errors with `[BitmapPixelFormat]::Bgra8`.

Comment: `[BitmapPixelFormat]::Unknown` should do, everything else looks alright

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, OK, weird situation.  Turns out that even though `Unknown` is clearly in the list, tying to use it produces this error: Exception calling "GetSoftwareBitmapAsync" with "5" argument(s): "The parameter is incorrect.
Windows.Graphics.Imaging: The bitmap pixel format is unsupported."

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, found a workaround for the problem.  But thank you for offering what really should have been the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why `GetSoftwareBitmapAsync` doesn't like `[BitmapPixelFormat]::Unknown`, but here is the solution I found.

I need to first load the image to see if it needs rotating. That is done with the original command:

```
$AsyncTask = $BitmapDecoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync()
$SoftwareBitmap = GetAsync( $AsyncTask, ([SoftwareBitmap]) )
```

Then extract its BitmapPixelFormat:

```
$BitmapPixelFormat = $SoftwareBitmap.BitmapPixelFormat
```

And then use $BitmapPixelFormat for all calls to the 5 parameter version of `GetSoftwareBitmapAsync()`.